# How to white list some ip and all the rest block while having already a DMZ?

Tags: linux, networking, router, firewall, iptables

I have a Linux machine running which has local ip: 192.168.1.2 
connected to a router with public IP 8.8.8.8, now the router 8.8.8.8 has DMZ to 192.168.1.2

As a result spammers, hackers, crackers crash the 192.168.1.2 running  H.323 protocol or SIP protocol.

How can i put a white list of public IP in the router or behind the router to prevent from such attack? (Linux machine is not open source i do not have access to place iptables on it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your router if you can run iptables, default drop anything incoming on the outward-facing interface, and then add exceptions:

A simple example of what you describe, presuming eth1 is the outward-facing device:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -j DROP
iptables -I FORWARD -i eth1 -s 123.123.123.123 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD -i eth1 -s 123.124.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT
```

The lines mean the following:

1. Allow traffic already vouched for, such as responses to your own queries
2. Drop everything
3. Allow IP `123.123.123.123`
4. Allow the entire subnet `123.124.xxx.xxx`

Note the switch to `-I` instead of `-A` on lines 3 and 4. This means that the rule should be placed first in the list instead of appending it.

If you need to run this on the linux machine itself, the same should work, but you need to substitute `FORWARD` with `INPUT`, and you can skip the input interface. In addition, you probably want to add an `ACCEPT` rule for `192.168.1.0/24` as your LAN is most likely trustworthy.

For more info, see [this tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo) or [the manual](http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables.man.html)